# 8 - Node::load is generating an object with circular reference which is crashing kint() and var_export()

Tags: 8, debugging

I have a content type with a Taxonomy term which has fields. When I try and load a node (or possibly nodes) of this type I get unexpected results. While debugging with kint() and var_export() I get errors about "circular references". Is this normal in Drupal 8 node structures?

Or is there an underlying misconfig in the content type or taxonomy causing this problem?

Comment: I believe typed data can cause circular references via the parent property.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal and by design.

When you want to dump it, just use $node->toArray(). Then you get an array with the plain values. You can use those field names and properties again to access the values on the node object, e.g. `$node->yourfield->value`.