# How do I access the protected value of node entity?

Tags: 8, nodes

I have a view node and I use the below code to Kint out the node objects:

```
$node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('node')
      ->loadMultiple();
 dpm($node);
```

returns the below output:

[image]

I get to see the properties of each node. In this, I want to access the target_id/value of the highlighted field - field_cp_level2_ref_level3. I tried the below line and it is coming out as null:

```
$node->field_cp_level2_ref_level3->target_id
```

How to access this field value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [8 - Node::load is generating an object with circular reference which is crashing kint() and var\_export()](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200046/8-nodeload-is-generating-an-object-with-circular-reference-which-is-crashing)

Comment: When you want to dump it, just use $node->toArray() , Refer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/200118/71454

Comment: @misstudent2011 I'm not mentioning that my page is crashing due to circular reference generated. I'm just asking a way to access the protected values. The question you have referenced does not help me.

Comment: have you gone through the answer in the link I shared ? It provides you the way to get the protected values. Seems you are having difficulty to get it let me paste it as comment.

Comment: When you want to dump it, just use `$node->toArray()`. Then you get an array with the plain values. You can use those field names and properties again to access the values on the node object, e.g. `$node->yourfield->value.`

Comment: Thanks @miststudent2011 but doing a $node->toArray returns the below error: "Error: Call to a member function toArray() on array" . also doing $node->yourfield->value returns null :(

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you wrongly assume the result of `loadMultiple` to be a node object, when instead it returns an array of node objects.

You should be able to do this:

```
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('node')
  ->loadMultiple();
$node = reset($nodes);
```

You should now be able to access the values you see in your debug output:

```
$node->field_cp_level2_ref_level3->target_id;
```

It's actually a bit questionable to load all the nodes you have in your system. That might still work with your 294 nodes, but it will create problems on sites with more content. Instead you should add conditions, e.g. by using `loadByProperties` on the node storage.